# Showing profile picture in contacts screen in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Are there any plugins or options in Outlook (specifically 2003) to display the picture associated with contacts in the contact screens?

The pictures show up on my smartphone after I sync. I'd like to see the photos, at a glance, in Outlook itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion is to move on to Outlook 2007, where the contacts list contains the picture by default. Outlook 2003 seems to have excluded by purpose the picture as a possible addition to the Contacts list view fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try [XOBNI](http://www.xobni.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you customize the Outlook Contact template?

Basically, any modification to the Outlook Contact template causes it to revert to the older display format where the Contact photo is not available. This change could have been done by yourself or some product that you've installed.

Comment: that contact photo is available when i look at each individual contact, when reading the details, it's NOT available when i'm looking at the list of contacts.  That is where I want the photos to display.